# Materialize css select not working with jquery steps

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize, jquery-steps

I'm having trouble getting a Materialize css select element to work within a jQuery Steps wizard. And I found that this guy Jon Vadillo are having the same issue with his example on CodePen (https://codepen.io/jonvadillo/pen/xObWmw).

When clicking the select element, it never activates. I have tried moving the select element outside of the jQuery Steps wizard and everything works as intended. (https://codepen.io/allanlange/pen/EWQzBb)

```js
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  min: new Date(),
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  firstDay: 1
});

var picker = $('#beginDate').pickadate('picker');
picker.set('select', new Date());
var picker = $('#endDate').pickadate('picker');
picker.set('select', new Date());


$('select').material_select();


var form = $("#example-form");
form.children("div").steps({
  headerTag: "h3",
  bodyTag: "section",
  transitionEffect: "slideLeft",

  /* Labels */
  labels: {
    cancel: "Cancel?",
    current: "current step:",
    pagination: "Pagination",
    finish: "Finish!!",
    next: "Next >",
    previous: "< Previous",
    loading: "Loading ..."
  },


  onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

    return true;
  },
  onFinishing: function(event, currentIndex) {

    return true;
  },
  onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
    alert("Submitted!");
  }
});
```

```css
/*
    Common 
*/

.wizard,
.tabcontrol {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a {
  outline: 0;
}

.wizard ul,
.tabcontrol ul {
  list-style: none !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wizard ul>li,
.tabcontrol ul>li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Accessibility */

.wizard>.steps .current-info,
.tabcontrol>.steps .current-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

.wizard>.content>.title,
.tabcontrol>.content>.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}


/*
    Wizard
*/

.wizard>.steps {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical>.steps {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.wizard>.steps .number {
  font-size: 1.429em;
}

.wizard>.steps>ul>li {
  width: 25%;
}

.wizard>.steps>ul>li,
.wizard>.actions>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

.wizard.vertical>.steps>ul>li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard>.steps a,
.wizard>.steps a:hover,
.wizard>.steps a:active {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard>.steps .disabled a,
.wizard>.steps .disabled a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .disabled a:active {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
}

.wizard>.steps .current a,
.wizard>.steps .current a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .current a:active {
  background: #2184be;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.wizard>.steps .done a,
.wizard>.steps .done a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .done a:active {
  background: #9dc8e2;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard>.steps .error a,
.wizard>.steps .error a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .error a:active {
  background: #ff3111;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard>.actions {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical>.actions {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
}

.wizard>.actions>ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.wizard>.actions>ul>li {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.wizard.vertical>.actions>ul>li {
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.wizard>.actions a,
.wizard>.actions a:hover,
.wizard>.actions a:active {
  background: #2184be;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard>.actions .disabled a,
.wizard>.actions .disabled a:hover,
.wizard>.actions .disabled a:active {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/master/build/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose event type</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    <label>Event type</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12">
    <form id="example-form">
      <div>
        <h3>Account</h3>
        <section>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input placeholder="Event title" id="title" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <select multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose style(s)</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
              <label>Styles</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <section>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <label>Begin date</label>
              <input id="beginDate" type="date" class="datepicker">

            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <label>End date</label>
              <input id="endDate" type="date" class="datepicker">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input placeholder="Who is organizing the event?" id="organizer" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="organizer">Organizer</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="http://www.mywebsite.com" id="website" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="website">Website</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="contact@myweb.com" id="email" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Contact email</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <textarea id="description" class="materialize-textarea" length="140"></textarea>
              <label for="description">Describe the event in a tweet!</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found solution, wrapping `$('select').material_select();` in `$(document).ready` solves the issue

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

Here's codepen link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBjNJd 
with changes added to https://codepen.io/jonvadillo/pen/xObWmw